# combine two tables in mysql with different column names

Tags: mysql

Trying to combine two tables with different columns and rows

TABLE_1

```
|     id_product      | product_state_1  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         106002      |        1         |
|         114000      |        0         |
|         106005      |        1         |
|         106004      |        1         |
```

TABLE_2

```
|     id_product      |  product_state_2 |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         106002      |        0         |
|         114000      |        1         |
|         106005      |        1         |
|         109005      |        1         |
```

Required result_table

```
|     id_product      |  product_state_1 | product_state_2  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         106002      |        1         |   0              |
|         114000      |        0         |   1              |
|         106005      |        1         |   1              |
|         109005      |        NULL      |   1              |
|         106004      |        1         |   NULL           |
```

```
I tried the following code with the UNION
```

SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE_2;

```
but the following code does not give the required result.
```

Comment: Hi @anna please just JOIN two tables with id. Use LEFT or INNER JOIN as per your business.

Comment: unfortunately that isn't working either

Comment: what is the relation between two tables if you want to join two tables having different columns.?

Comment: This question is not duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` `JOIN` along with `UNION`:

```
SELECT t1.id_product, t1.product_state_1, t2.product_state_2 
FROM TABLE_1 t1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2
ON t1.id_product = t2.id_product
UNION
SELECT t2.id_product, t1.product_state_1, t2.product_state_2 
FROM TABLE_1 t1 
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_2 t2
ON t1.id_product = t2.id_product;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbkkbUdHhmhAzqrEpSPx4a/4)

Comment: thank you. But what if I have an id_product that exists only in one table? I would lose that information on performing an inner join.

Comment: I have just edited the question.

Comment: Hi @anna, Updated my answer with new query.